# Can't get rails tests to even run, UNIQUE constraint failed: reviews.id:

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, testing, sqlite

I'm beginning to look at testing a Rails app I've been working on and can't seem to get the default generated tests to even run. I think it has something to do with rails generating unique ids for fixtures.

The test I'm running is simply this: 
rails test test/controllers/pages_controller_test

Full error message: 
Error:
PagesControllerTest#test_should_get_home:
ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique: SQLite3::ConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint failed: reviews.id: INSERT INTO "reviews" ("created_at", "updated_at", "id") VALUES ('2018-03-26 21:55:24.345073', '2018-03-26 21:55:24.345073', 980190962)

test/controllers/pages_controller_test

```
require 'test_helper'

class PagesControllerTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  test "should get home" do
    get pages_home_url
    assert_response :success
  end

end
```

This is what reviews.yml looks like:

```
# Read about fixtures at 
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FixtureSet.html

one:
  comment: MyText
  star: 1
  reservation_id: one
  tourist_id: one
  guide_id: one
  type:

two:
  comment: MyText
  star: 1
  reservation_id: two
  tourist_id: two
  guide_id: two
  type:
```

Comment: odd. if you temporarily remove the second review - does the error go away?

Comment: I removed it and ran the command again and nothing changed. I'm new to rails, is there anything I had to do before running that command in the first place?

Comment: No that should be fine. Hmmm... if removing one didn't fix it... then the error might be coming from somewhere else. be certain by first temporarily deleting the reviews.yaml file altogether. Also - can you check `log/test.log` and look for the other lines of the error? there should be a whole slew of lines that look like filenames with line-numbers after them (called the stacktrace). This will help us figure out which file+line of code is actually causing the error.

Comment: Actually, deleting the file does not seem to get rid of the error. I want to post what the log looks like but I think it's too messy to copy paste it onto here. It looks like it is actually inserting a review object with id 980190962 twice when it runs a test. Here: https://imgur.com/a/9BTrU

Comment: It's ok to edit your question and post the relevant lines there, then add code-formatting. Comments have awful code-formatting though yeah :P Interesting to me is that there are two lines of reviews added (that you've highlighted) and that have *different* ids... and then right at the bottom of all the other inserts is one more review-insert... so my best guess so far is that there are somehow two review-fixture files...

Comment: Make sure, that database are cleaned after or before executing tests.